# The 'Learn more' or 'Book now' Call to Action problem on overview pages

Tags: information-architecture, conversion, call-to-action

I need help thinking this through: There are holiday packages to be sold so I have an overview template that shows the collection of packages and a single detail template that explains the details (of course).

Now on the overview page the client insists on having both a **learn more** and **book now** button. I think the book now button is redundant there because no one is going to book a package without having seen the details.

So now my questions are:

1. How do you weigh the choices and rule out the wrong one?
2. How do I measure which one was right?
3. Does it make sense to say that one choice is primary and the other is secondary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all comes down to two factors: business strategy and user needs.

It seems like you have a pretty clear pressure from the business strategy side of the world to include both CTAs; what do you have from the user side of things? Do you have any research to support one view or the other? Have you tried using usertesting.com with a quick prototype or perhaps one of the OptimalSort tools?

As for measuring which is right, if you are in an iterative environment (as in, you can change it if it performs horribly) do it the way they say, establish clear measures of success (low abandon rates, high conversion, etc.) and see what happens.

It's best practice to have one be primary and the other be secondary. My initial and ignorant view is that "learn more" would be primary and "book now" would be secondary. If someone clicks "learn more" they can still "book now" on the next page. If someone clicks "book now" and was really wanting to "learn more" they need to abandon their current path.